# display map content in angular 4 template

Tags: angular

I'm trying to display a map in my template :

```
myMap : Map<string, Array<ATypeOfMine>>
```

Tried to use a

```
<div *ngFor="let myStuff of myMap.entries()">
    ...
</div>
```

I'm getting an error telling I can't iterate over anything but an Array. And I can't find any way to get my entries and work on them

Any idea ?

Answer (score 15):

Angular has a given pipe called "KeyValuePipe".

```
<div *ngFor="let mapEntry of myMap | keyvalue"></div>
```

The KeyValuePipe returns a model w/ Angular's KeyValue shape. So to access your string key, you'd chain:

```
mapEntry.key
```

To access your ATypeOfMine array values, you'd chain:

```
mapEntry.value.____etc
```

The default order the KeyValuePipe will be sorted by unicode. If you wanted to sort them by insertion order, you'd have to pass the map pipe a compareFn, and add an index property per value.

I use this:

```
(akv: KeyValue<number, any>, bkv: KeyValue<number, any>): number => {
  const a = akv.value.index;
  const b = bkv.value.index;

  return a > b ? 1 : (b > a ? -1 : 0);
}
```

* I found the above compare fn from another stack overflow thread.

Answer (score 1):

the correct way is

```
get mapEntries() { return Array.from(this.myMap.entries()); }
```

In your HTML

```
<xxx *ngFor="let mapEntry of mapEntries">{{ myMap.get(mapEntry[0]) }}</xxx>
```

Comment: .entries() is not found as if myMap wasn't actually a map. is there something wrong with the myMap declaration ?

Comment: Is it possible my app is not properly configured to transpile my .entries() to es5 ?

Answer (score 1):

`map.entries()` returns a `MapIterator` which you can iterate over using `.next`. `*ngFor` only iterates over arrays and does not iterate using the [iterator protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators), which `MapIterator` implements.

[Maps are intentionally not supported](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2246) because they are not ordinal.

If you want to convert `.entries` to an array you can do so via `Array.from()` which will give you an array that looks like:

```
[["key1", "val1"], ["key2", "val2"]]
```

You could also use `Array.from(map.keys())` which will return `["key1", "key2"]` and you could iterate over it like so:

```
<div *ngFor="let key of mapKeys">{{ myMap.get(key) }}</div>
```

You could also create a pipe to transform the map to an array as well:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({name: 'mapToArray'})
export class MapToArray implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: Map): Array {
    const entries = value.entries();
    const result = [];
    let done = false;
    while (!done) {
      const { value: currentValue, done: isDone } = entries.next();
      result.push(currentValue);
      done = isDone;
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Then you could use what you have as `*ngFor="let values of myMap | mapToArray"`

In summary, as you can see there are a lot of different ways you can handle iteration over a map which has something to do with why it doesn't work by default. It's up to you to figure out the best way to do it depending on your use case (if you need the keys for example).

Comment: Still it's a good solution, it feels kind of weird it's not native, doesn't it ?

Comment: @Seb it's not native because there are so many different possible solutions

Answer (score 0):

This is complementary answer to address debugging purposes, as sometimes you need a quick way to see a `Map`. In this case there is a designated pipe (`keyvalue` ) that must be used along with the classic `json` pipe:

```
{{myMap | keyvalue | json}}
```