# How to access key values from array object in Angular with ngFor

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ngfor

Every time a module expansion panel is clicked, a HTTP call is made to the API to get all the companies available to the particular module.

```
  <mat-accordion *ngIf="modules">
    <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let module of modules">
      <mat-expansion-panel-header (click)="availableCompanies(module.module_name)">
        <mat-panel-title>
          {{module.module_name}}
        </mat-panel-title>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
```

HTTP response (available companies):

```
{
  "message": "Retrieved companies available to module",
  "data": [
    { "co_code": "123", "name": "Company A" },
    { "co_code": "456", "name": "Company B" },
    { "co_code": "789", "name": "Company C" }
  ]
}
```

#### My Problem:

Inside each module expansion panel, I want to then display the available companies as a checklist. But I'm having trouble accessing the key values of the object and iterating for each checkbox. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
      <mat-list dense>
        <mat-list-item *ngFor="let vertical of companies | keys">
          <mat-checkbox *ngFor="let company of companies[vertical]">
            {{company.name}}
          </mat-checkbox>
        </mat-list-item>
      </mat-list>
```

I think maybe I need to change how I'm using the keys pipe or the ngFor? Any help or ideas would be awesome, thanks :)

#### Extra Information:

Here's the list.component.ts:

```
export class listComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() modules: Module[];
  @Input() companies: Company[] = [];

  constructor(
    private rs: RecipientService, // has getAvailableCompanies http method
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  availableCompanies(vertical: string) {
   this.rs.getAvailableCompanies(this.recipient.email_address, vertical).subscribe(res => {
     this.companies[vertical] = res;
     console.log(res);
     console.log(this.companies);
   });
  }

}
```

**console.log(res):**

```
(3) [
     { "co_code": "123", "name": "Company A" }, 
     { "co_code": "456", "name": "Company B" }, 
     { "co_code": "789", "name": "Company C" }
    ]
```

**console.log(this.companies)**
keeps track of modules/verticals clicked.
If two modules have been expanded (credit_cards and deposits), this.companies stores the module_names (keys) and the array of companies available each:

```
[credit_cards: Array(3), deposits: Array(4)]
```

Comment: see this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor

Comment: [Iterate through objects using ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54875748/10675972)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to use  [**`keyvalue`**](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe)  but with wrong syntax,

you need use **`keyvalue`** not as just **`keys`** unless you have a custom pipe declaration.

```
<mat-list dense>
     <mat-list-item *ngFor="let vertical of companies | keyvalue">
         <mat-checkbox *ngFor="let company of companies[vertical]">
            {{company.name}}
         </mat-checkbox>
     </mat-list-item>
 </mat-list>
```